# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined while building my own react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to build my own react from https://blog.javascripting.com/2016/10/05/building-your-own-react-clone-in-five-easy-steps/
I am new to React.I looked into other answers for similar question but those are not working.
My understanding is that is 'map' try to use children of String 'Welcome Ramesh'. Since there is no children so throwing this error.
I try to wrap newElement with if condition (element.children !== undefined) then getting error "return newElement" not able to access newElement. So posting here for optimal solution
Error message
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0Lpk.png)

```
/** @jsx h */
const h = (type, props = {}, children = []) => ({  
  type,
  props,
  children
});


const WelcomeComponent = ({ name }) => h('div', {}, ['Welcome ' + name]);

const RootComponent = ({ user }) => {  
  if (user) {
    // The vDOM node's type can also be another
    // component. React calls it automatically when creating
    // the vDOM tree
    return h(WelcomeComponent, { name: user.name });
  } else {
    return h('div', {}, [`Please, Log in`]);
  }
}

// To simplify the correlation of nodes in the vDOM and DOM,
// we generate a unique ID for each DOM node. These are just
// dot-delimited paths containing the index of each child in
// the list of children maintained by its parent.
// This allows us to use simple string manipulation to implement
// advanced features like a synthetic event system
const createVDOM = (element, id = '.') => {  
  // This function must be called recursively for all descendants
  // in order to transform the entire tree
  console.log("element is",element," and id is",id)

  const newElement = {
    ...element,
    id,
    children: element.children.map((child, index) => createVDOM(child, `${id}${index}.`))
  };
  console.log("newElement is",newElement)
  // Is this a component?
  if (typeof element.type === 'function') {
    // Call the component and pass in the props.
    // Returns the generated subtree

    const subtree = newElement.type(element.props);
    console.log("subtree is",subtree)

    // Call ourself recursively in order to assign the right ID
    // to the nodes and process any subcomponents in the subtree
    return createVDOM(subtree, id);
  } else {
    // If we come across an element that is not a function,
    // all we have to do is return it
    console.log("return New Element is",newElement)
    return newElement
    //return document.createTextNode(element);
  }
};
/*
const a = (
  <ul class="list">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
  </ul>
);
*/
const $root = document.getElementById('root');
console.log("The file is loaded")
$root.appendChild(createVDOM(RootComponent({ user: { name: 'Ramesh' } })));
```

Comment: `map` is an array method, therefor `element.children` should be an array, if you log `console.log(typeof element.children)` what is your output? Or when you log element.children directly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are passing only one argument to map:

children: element.children.map **((child, index) => createVDOM(child, `${id}${index}.`)    )**

Can you try to pass the function you want to trigger as the second argument instead of using lambda exp?

ref: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html